# WP in docker container hacked - Server sends Phishing mails - disable container from other OS with the server volume mounted?

Tags: linux, docker, phishing, linux-vserver

Wordpress that has not been updated in a docker container on a vServer has probably been hacked  since the provider notified me about the server sending phishing mails and deactivated my machine.

Now they let me run a rescue linux from where I can mount the former server SSD. Can anyone tell me how to prevent the specific container from running when the original OS is powered up again? Cause obviously I can't call the docker daemon to set any parameters ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual solution would be to delete or move `/var/lib/docker/containers`. Inside of each sub-folder will be a `config.v2.json` and `hostconfig.json` which you may be able adjust by hand, particularly the entry in `hostconfig.json` for:

```
"RestartPolicy":{"Name":"always","MaximumRetryCount":0}
```

which you can try changing to:

```
"RestartPolicy":{"Name":"","MaximumRetryCount":0}
```

You can also simply disable the Docker service, depending on how that is launched.

Comment: I see the folders in the /containers/ folder, but since their names are hashes, how do i find the right folder for the container I want to change the .config?

Comment: You'd need to look in each directory.